# googleMapsApp(project name) wont run without google play services. which are not supported by your device

Tags: android, google-maps, genymotion

i'm working on an application that uses the google map services To display the location of the user on the map.
but when i'm trying to run it on the genymotion device(android version 7.0), the following error displays on the screen:

> googleMapsApp(project name) wont run without google play services.
>   which are not supported by your device.

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Android SDK provides emulator with google play services...
Did you try to use it?

[image: see here]

Comment: Unfortunately not. because it does'nt run on AMD processors.